# Using linq to select possible values for multiple database columns in one SQL query (EF6)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Say I have a table `Entity` with `Col1, Col2,... Coln...`.

And in my app I have `List1, List2,... Listn`. I need to load the possible values in columns to lists respectively.

I can do this with multiple linq queries:

```
list1 = await context.Entities.Select(e => e.Col1).Distinct().ToListAsync();
list2 = await context.Entities.Select(e => e.Col2).Distinct().ToListAsync();
...
```

I can also do it concurrently, but it still involves multiple SQL queries, one for each column (list).

Is it possible to do this in just one SQL query?

I'm using EF6 as ORM.

Comment: A strange requirement. Either your columns don't belong in the same table or your Lists should merge.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The scenario is like this: we have a Person table with columns like region code, department, group, etc. Ideally these columns should be pointer to other tables (RegionCode, Department, Group, etc) But they are all stored as strings and I cannot change that.
Now in the page, I need to populate dropdowns to select possible values. So I'll have RegionCode dropdown, Department dropdown, Group dropdown...

Comment: Ok, "your columns don't belong in the same table" but that's beyond your control.  Then EF is not going to help, afaik. Either do 1 big query and do the `.Distnct().ToList()` in-memory or do the multiple queries.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to return data for UI dropdown lists or lookup controls. I would advise for a store proc or function. You can control what columns can be returned by using enum types. This way your consumers don't pass strings for column names, but your model controls which columns distinct values can be retrieved this way.

Comment: Sounds like a classic use case for Future Queries, which are supported by e.g. The Entity Framework Plus extension package

Comment: @JonasHøgh Hi Jonas, just had a quick look at the Future Queries and it looks promising. Could you please elaborate the idea in an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can't do:

```
var list1 = await context.Entities.Select(e => new { e.Col1, e.Cal2}).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

because the distinct is a different in this case (combined distinct)

you can try the JOIN option, but then you have 1 result list which you might to split into two lists, to have the same results.
As long, you want two lists as a result, there is no much better solution without other drawbacks.

Consider to do a View / Materialized View on Database level, in particular if the tables are bigger.
But even then, if you do one request, you have one result list.

a more parallel version of your code:

```
var task1= context.Entities.Select(e => e.Col1).Distinct().ToListAsync();
var task2 = context.Entities.Select(e => e.Col2).Distinct().ToListAsync();

var list1 = await task1;
var list2 = await task2;
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is impossible. I don't think your code is more parallel though. `Task` would be more appropriate for this scenario, IMHO.